# My php homepage downloads index.php instead of being processed on Gandi.net

Tags: php, .htaccess, website

if I go to the homepage of my website http://www.website.com (on a brand new server) the index.php gets donwloaded instead than processed. 
I don't have the same problem on other folders.
my .htaccess reads:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

what could this be?
I suspect it's something with php config / or htaccess, but I'm not able to figure it out.
help please!

edit: I don't know if this helps:
it's a wordpress installation, I have this problem only on the public part of the website, not on the admin (that renders correctly)

Answer (score 2):

I believe your handler is wrong. According to http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHPDownload you need to use:

```
# (other modules)
# Replace the following with the correct path and version of your php module
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
# (other modules)

<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: thank you, I tried to change my .htaccess with your code but nothing changes.. is there a way I can test if the module is loading correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Try a simple script, to see if it works. There could be a problem in index.php.

```
in test.php: 
    <?php echo phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: he already said it wasn't parsed.

Comment: Mathew - I've moved wordpress installations before and encountered this exact problem, that's why I said that. When I first encountered this, I was also under the assumption that there was an apache config problem, until I discovered that other files were being served just fine, similar to him above saying that the admin pages are being served correctly.