# /var/www/ downloads php files instead of viewing them in browser

Tags: ubuntu, php, lamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My php homepage downloads index.php instead of being processed on Gandi.net](https://serverfault.com/questions/216164/my-php-homepage-downloads-index-php-instead-of-being-processed-on-gandi-net)

hi im a newbie with servers so thats why i come here with my prob hoping you can help me.
so ubuntu 11.10 and i installed lamp-server but the problem is that i was screwing with file-permissions and stuff and now everything i have to http://localhost/index.php my browser attempts to download the index.php instead of viewing it in the browser.

Is there some sort of way to reset /var/www/ to default settings? if no what is the best way to reinstall lamp-server with default settings?

any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: That means someone else asked a similar question.  Have you read the link and seen the solutions there fix your problem?  If they don't please tell us that you tried the solution, and what happened.

Comment: Ok i tried something different... if i just take files from windows to my ftp they do not get downloaded but displayed. But if i drag and drop from a tar.gz they get downloaded if i head over to them.. (ffmpeg-php.tar.gz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several things that could cause this...  I am going to assume that because you mentioned permissions, that permissions are the problem:

Run the following commands as root:

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
```

Also, be sure to clear your browser's cache...  The process is different for every browser, so if you don't know how, just leave a comment with your web browser or choice...

**EDIT:** Added the second command, it may not be the most secure thing in the world, but it will let us work backwards from a known-working state...